# RPi2 raspbian I2C error - BMP180 sensor

Tags: pi-2, i2c, bmp180

I am having a lot of trouble getting the RPi2 to recognize the sensor, even after configuring the I<sup>2</sup>C for the RPi and following the [guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/using-the-bmp085-with-raspberry-pi/configuring-the-pi-for-i2c) several times.

Running:

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 1
```

outputs that nothing is connected.

I've tried connected the BMP180 to both 5V and 3.3V, and using multiple different grounds, but have not gotten anything to work; has this happened to anyone else before?

`hive-node.py` is the script running on the RPi, and only the BMP180 does not work: https://github.com/trevstanhope/hive-node

[image: pi 2 pins]

[image: bmp180 pins]

[image: output of sudo i2cdetect -y 1]
[image: gpio-readall]

Comment: If you want help you will have to detail the connections you have made between the Pi and the sensor and preferably also include a photo.

Comment: Have you followed this guide to setup i2c correctly ? https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c it's not enabled by default.

Comment: @dastaan, i followed that guide front to back a few times and was not able to successfully get it running,

Comment: @joan, great suggestion, I will add a photo right now.

Comment: @joan: photos added

Comment: The connections look okay.  What is actually reported by i2cdetect -y 1? Is it the expected grid or an error message?

Comment: the grid is empty, i will, edit the OP and include a screenshot.

Comment: Did you run raspi-config->Advanced->enable I2C, add the modules, remove the blacklisted items and added the lines in config.txt as per the tutorial?

Comment: @PhilB. i2cdetect would fail with a /dev/i2c-1 error if the modules were not correctly loaded.  @ Evan Could you check that the gpios 2 and 3 are actually in I2C mode (ALT0).  Perhaps they have been set as inputs or outputs.  If you have wiringPi installed you could use its gpio readall command.  Alternatively with my [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library you could use pigs mg 2 and pigs mg 3.

Comment: @PhilB., Yes I ran everything according to the tutorial, the only difference was the blacklist file did not have any items.

Comment: @joan, GPIO.2 and GPIO.3 are both set as inputs. SDA.1 and SCL.1, the pins that the BMP180 use, are both in the ATL0 mode. Do you mean that I  should be using GPIO.2 and GPIO.3 as ALT0?...I added a screen capture of the gpio-readall

Comment: No, what you have is correct.  GPIO.2 and GPIO.3 are arbitrary names used by wiringPi.  The BCM column shows the gpio numbers and gpios 2 and 3 are shown as correctly set to ALT0.  It is starting to seem likely that your sensor is faulty.  Do you have another I2C device?  I'd try powering sensor Vin from 5V and then sensor 3V3 from 3V3.  If neither of those work I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Hmm, ok thank you. I have two bmp 180s, so i will try both of them in both  3.3v and 5v combinations. thanks for your help

Comment: Still no luck, tried every combination with both sensors.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with the BMP180 sensor module I have (not exactly like your adafruit? one), it can periodically refuse to respond to I2C, seemingly at random. There is a soft-reset command for this chip, but no way to issue it if it doesn't respond to I2C.  The only option is power-cycling. Did you try power-cycling your BMP180 by pulling out the jumper on its Vin pin (leaving everything else connected and running)?  If that helps, you may be able to connect the BMP180's Vin to another Pi DIO so you can power cycle the BMP180 in software.  Not sure if the Raspberry PI's DIO current limit will be enough to power the BMP180 though.  If not, you can use a PFET.

Comment: It depend on the current requirements - the Vin pin on the board is connected to the 3.3V RPi rail SO THAT THE BMP180 uses 3.3V logic levels for it's I2C connections.  There is the alternative of using the 5V rail and spending a couple of pounds for an I2C 3V3 to 5V level shifter neede for the RPi connection to the bus, so you could use pFET control of that 5V power supply to the BMP180.  In general running I2C at 5V is a little more reliable - or at least it allows for a higher frequency of operation or longer maximum bus lengths then at 3.3V ...

Comment: Its no problem to put a logic-level pFET between the RPi 3.3V and the I2C 3.3V. You just need to pick one with a 3V or less gate drive voltage, and a low Rds-on (since it's powering the sensors). These are not exotic these days and < $1 in singles.  The gate can be driven directly by a DIO pin without additional components:  pFET-S to RPi 3V3, pFET-D to I2C 3V3, pFET-G to a free RPi DIO.  Set the pFET-G LOW to turn on I2C 3V3.

Answer (score 0):

The way I remember, GND is on pin 6, not 9. 9 is DNC.
Connect GND to pin 6 and recheck

Comment: Pin 6 & 9 (physical) are both ground; this is confirmed in the `gpio readall` output.  The black wire in the photo is connected correctly, as are the others.

Comment: On early Pi schematics some pins were marked as DNC in case they had to be changed to a different type of pin.  No DNCs were actually changed in purpose and there are no longer any pins marked as DNC.